# Host file hijack

Tags: windows-10, icons, gaming, hosts-file

I wanted to add an entry into my host file so I opened the directory and

Hosts
Networks
Protocol
Services

All files except the Imhosts.sam file are messed up.

all 4 of those files when double clicked somehow now start up Mass Effect 2.
Before I noticed a few random icons had change to the ME2 icon but the icons still functioned as they should.

How could this happen and more importantly how do I fix it?
Win10.

Comment: Files have automatic openers by file type.  If mass effect 2 was assigned to open files with null file types then it would.  If you can right click the file and select **open with**.  **Choose app** then select notepad and check the always option.  Then you can confirm if that fixes the launching of mass effect 2

Comment: I don't really care about ME2 that is working fine.
What is bothering me is that my host file is launching ME2.....

Comment: Try Clicking the .sam file and click open with and Select Notepad. And see if this fixes it.

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: Open With still works as intended and the file is opened up as a txt file in notepad if I chose it from the menu, however it still starts the ME2 launcher when double clicked so if it can't actuate on its own like that makes me wonder if it is doing its job.

Comment: Thanks David, looks like the mods have fixed that for me now.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something set your default program for no extension files to be ME2.  If you feel comfortable editing the registry, (there is a potential for damage here so follow things exactly), you can navigate to: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts and then left-click on the "." in there.  This will highlight it and now you should right-click on it.  Click on the "Export" option and save that file to the desktop, (this will give you a backup point should anything go wrong for the key that you have highlighted).  After that, click on the "+" plus sign to open up the folder and make sure the only folder in there is: "OpenWithList".  After you do that, delete all of the entries except for "Default".  The only thing in default should be: (value not set).  Really it shouldn't matter if there's anything else in the default entry, so don't fret if there is.

If you have a problem after doing any of this, then double-click on the file you exported at the start to undo the damage you may have done to that key.  Mind you, if you did any thing not listed in here, then that damage will not be undone by the file you exported and you may be in trouble.

Edit:
I should have been a little more specific, so I apologize for that.  On the right hand side of the Regedit window there could be some entries as well, make sure you delete those as well.  I've posted a screen shot of both folders for you.  The right hand side should only have the default entries.
[Screen shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS2g0.png)

---

Edit 2:
Okay, it looks like I was a bit off on what I told you earlier, so I apologize for that.  The method above fixes files with a "." period at the end of a file name and no extension.  You need to reset the file association with no period at all.  If you look at: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown`, you'll probably see that your game is listed in one or more of the entries inside of there.  Left click on `Unknown` then right-click on it and export that key entry to somewhere safe, (always backup before messing with the registry).  Next open up notepad or your plain text editor of choice and paste this into it, (this version is for Windows 7):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown]
"AlwaysShowExt"=""
"QueryClassStore"=""
"TypeOverlay"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
  65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell]
@="openas"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\openas]
"MultiSelectModel"="Single"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\openas\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,72,00,75,00,\
  6e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,25,00,53,\
  00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,\
  79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,\
  00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,4f,00,70,00,65,00,6e,00,41,00,\
  73,00,5f,00,52,00,75,00,6e,00,44,00,4c,00,4c,00,20,00,25,00,31,00,00,00
"DelegateExecute"="{e44e9428-bdbc-4987-a099-40dc8fd255e7}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\opendlg]
"LegacyDisable"=""
"MultiSelectModel"="Single"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\opendlg\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,72,00,75,00,\
  6e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,25,00,53,\
  00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,\
  79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,\
  00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,4f,00,70,00,65,00,6e,00,41,00,\
  73,00,5f,00,52,00,75,00,6e,00,44,00,4c,00,4c,00,20,00,25,00,31,00,00,00
```

Or if you have Windows 10, use this one instead:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown]
"AlwaysShowExt"=""
"QueryClassStore"=""
"TypeOverlay"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
  65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell]
@="openas"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\InvokeDefaultVerbInOtherProcess]
"ProgrammaticAccessOnly"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\InvokeDefaultVerbInOtherProcess\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{e44e9428-bdbc-4987-a099-40dc8fd255e7}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\Open]
"MultiSelectModel"="Single"
"ProgrammaticAccessOnly"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\Open\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4f,00,70,00,\
  65,00,6e,00,57,00,69,00,74,00,68,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,22,00,25,\
  00,31,00,22,00,00,00
"DelegateExecute"="{e44e9428-bdbc-4987-a099-40dc8fd255e7}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\openas]
@=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,\
  68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,35,\
  00,33,00,37,00,36,00,00,00
"MultiSelectModel"="Single"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\openas\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4f,00,70,00,\
  65,00,6e,00,57,00,69,00,74,00,68,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,22,00,25,\
  00,31,00,22,00,00,00
"DelegateExecute"="{e44e9428-bdbc-4987-a099-40dc8fd255e7}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\OpenWithSetDefaultOn]
"MultiSelectModel"="Single"
"ProgrammaticAccessOnly"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\OpenWithSetDefaultOn\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4f,00,70,00,\
  65,00,6e,00,57,00,69,00,74,00,68,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,2d,00,6f,\
  00,76,00,65,00,72,00,72,00,69,00,64,00,65,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,\
  00,00
"DelegateExecute"="{e44e9428-bdbc-4987-a099-40dc8fd255e7}"
```

Next save it as: `"UnknownReset.reg"`, please note that the quotations are needed as notepad will automatically add the .txt extension if you don't have quotes around the file name.  Next, double-click on the newly created file and that should fix your issue.  If it saved the file with a .txt extension, then you'll have to remove the extension and try again, or manually import the data in Regedit.  To manually import, you can open Regedit, then click on the `File` menu and then `Import`.  Choose `All files` from the drop down and then choose the file you put the above code in.  So long as it was properly pasted into the file, it should work.

Comment: Blerg, There is another folder in there called OpenWithProgids. I deleted it as per your instructions but nothing changed. Only Default is listed inside OpenWithList so no keys to delete there. Anything further to add?

Comment: reboot??????????

Comment: Rebooting shouldn't be necessary after removing the keys and values.  It's queried each time a file is opened as far as I can tell.  I tested it on my machine too.

Comment: Yeah reboot should not be necessary for this but I did try it anyway, again nothing changed.

Comment: No need to be so specific Blerg, I am no stranger to editing the registry.
Looks like I should have explained better.
Under the "." there were two files OpenWithList and OpenWithProgids. I deleted OpenWithProgids as you said make sure there is only one folder. When I checked the OpenWithList folder there were no enteries on the right other than Default.

Comment: You might not be the only one with this problem.  Thar be dragons in the registry and newcomers might follow these steps.  :-)

Comment: Very true.
Sorry to say that the above is still not working

Comment: Not surprised now that I look at it.  I sent you mine, which is for Windows 7.  You need Windows 10, which I added to my answer.

Comment: I have not noticed any change with the new code either.